# argparse: required argument conditioned by boolean

Tags: python, argparse

What I'm trying to do is to call a python script with 2 arguments, let's say `--higher_level_optional_arg` and `--prepare_data`.

`--prepare_data` is a boolean defaulting to `False`.

Now the thing I'd like to accomplish but that I cannot figure out is:

**if** `--prepare_data` is `False` then a string argument `--data_tag` (used to point to the data) is required, **otherwise** `--data_tag` is not required but you can pass one or more optional arguments for data preparation, e.g. `--prepare_data_arg`.

I tried combining subparsers and mutually exclusive groups but I guess I'm too noob and I cannot make it work.

Can you help me or point me in the right direction ?

**EDIT :**
Better to explain with some code (my bad).

Here's my parser definition:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--higher_level_optional_arg",
        default=5,
        type=int,
        help="some optional arg",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--prepare_data",
        dest="prepare_data",
        default=False,
        action="store_true",
        help="wether you want to prepare data or not"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--data_tag",
        #required=True,
        type=str,
        help="if prepare_data is false, this should be required to retrieve existing data",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--prepare_data_arg",
        default=10,
        type=int,
        help="if prepare_data is true you can pass this if you want",
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    higher_level_optional_arg = args.higher_level_optional_arg
    prepare_data = args.prepare_data
    data_tag = args.data_tag
    prepare_data_arg = args.prepare_data_arg

    main()
```

Then, in `main`, as suggested by @hpaulj I can put the logic I need as:

```
def main():
    if not prepare_data:
        if not data_tag:
            raise Exception("you need to pass --data_tag to retrieve the existing data")
        else:
            # retrieve the data with the data_tag
            print("loading data...")
    else:
        # prepare the data using prepare_data_arg, if passed
        print("preparing data...")
```

But who's running the script doesn't know that `--data_tag` is required if `prepare_data==False` and s/he shouldn't receive an Exception for that, imo.

(**notice that `data_tag` is not required if `prepare_data==True` so I don't don't want to uncomment the `required=True`**)

My reformulated question is: **can I achieve what I'm doing here within the parser definition ?**

Comment: what about doing something like `if not prepare_data and not data_tag: print("Datatag is required") else: print("Everything OK")`

Comment: The problem is not to check whether the `data_tag` is present but how to declare it under the condition that `prepare_data` is `False`. In one of my tries when I tried to `.add_argument()` inside an `if` statement I got: `error: unrecognized arguments: --data_tag` even if I reparsed at the end

Comment: What do you mean by 'declare it under the condition that prepare_data is False'? Either the user gives it and you process in your script, otherwise you alert the user that a required tag is missing.

Comment: then put the add_argument inside a `try` and capture the exception if that tag doesn't exist. It would be better if you post the code you have, so we can help you based on some code.

Comment: generally it's easier to test for interactions like this after parsing than during. With the right default you won't care whether `data_tag` is given or not.

Comment: If you want to tell your user about this conditional requirement, you have to do so in the `help` and `description`.  There's no `usage` syntax to indicate that - in `usage` arguments are either required or not.  Life will be easier for you and your user if you keep the commandline requirements simple.  The primary purpose of parsing is to figure out what the user wants.

Comment: I don't believe such functionality is currently built into the `argparse` module. Your goal can still easily be implemented by coding the logic yourself.